# Why when I enter integer data, its value is always rounded in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Here I want to enter the value of the test result, where the data is integer based.

Plus, I would like to add up with other test results value data.

But why when I enter this integer-based data, its value is always rounded, or I get unsuitable results

in Controller Exam.php

```
public function Exam()
{
  $data_exam = array(
    'subjects' => 'Natural Sciences',
    'name_of_pupil' => 'Rizky Remangsa',
    'the_pure_value_of_the_exam' => 5.6,
    'addition_with_another_value' => 11.2,
    'student_address' => 'Indonesia/Jakarta Selatan',
    'graduation_status' => 'Not graduated yet'
  );
  $this->exam_model->insertDataExam($data_exam);
}
```

The results of the data entered above are:

table the_pure_value_of_the_exam = 6

table addition_with_another_value = 11

Comment: The values you're trying to enter are floats, not integers

Comment: Then how can i enter that data, but interger based. @NathanDawson

Comment: Integers are whole numbers therefore the values you're seeing, 6 and 11, are correct. They've been converted from floats to integers for you. To correctly insert you'd need to change the format you're storing the values in

Comment: Do you mean? Change its kind to Varchar, is that so? @NathanDawson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing your data in the wrong format so it's being converted for you.

`5.6` is a float, not an integer. Integers are whole numbers. If you enter that value into an integer field it will round it to the nearest whole number.

You need to change the format you're storing the value in to something more appropriate:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html

I'm making the assumption here that you're using MySQL but the same approach is going to apply regardless of the database type. Check the documentation to determine how best to store the data.

Comment: Thx,For the answer :), very helpful to me